# Can anyone tell me why this recursive function returns undefined instead of false or true?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a function that is supposed to recursively scan an array and determine if it contains a given value.

```
function includesNumber(arr, num) {
  if (arr.length === 1 && arr[0] !== num) {
    return false; 
  } else if (arr[0] === num) {
    return true;
  } else {
   arr = arr.slice(1);
   includesNumber(arr, num);
 }
}
```

I have examined it in a debugger, and I know that if I give it input that should result in a falsy value, say includesNumber([4,8,15,16,23,42], 5), it goes through all the proper steps and hits the first if condition. If I then type "arr.length === 1" it returns true, and if I type "arr[0] !== num" it also returns true, so it should meet all the criteria to return false. But instead, it returns undefined. I always seem to run into this problem with recursion, where it meets the proper conditions but returns undefined, and I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: The result of the recursive call is not returned: the result is actually *`undefined`* for most arrays (and in all cases when it does call itself recursively). Also, using `arr.slice(..)` yields bad O complexity for this task.

Comment: `return includesNumber(arr, num);`

Comment: Because you do not return from the recursion....

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a return on the function - see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2svta4ge/:

```
  function includesNumber(arr, num) {
  if (arr.length === 1 && arr[0] !== num) {
    return false; 
  } else if (arr[0] === num) {
    return true;
  } else {
   arr = arr.slice(1);
   return includesNumber(arr, num);
 }
}
```